# Hibernate query language like operator not working

Tags: java, hql

```
cmTDsquery = createQuery("from CmTxnDetailStage cstg where cstg.statusCd=:err" +
                    " and (cstg.id.batchName like :batchname or cstg.id.batchName like :batchname1)"+
                    " and cstg.prodTypeBlfd like :search1 "+
                    " and trunc(cstg.tranUploadDttm)=:uploadDt");
cmTDsquery.bindStringProperty("search1", CmTxnDetailStage.properties.prodTypeBlfd, search);
```

I declared the search parameter as

```
search = "MON%";
```

If I replace the `:search1` with `'MON%'` ,It works fine and query returns result.

Only above code does not work and returns `NULL`.

Thanks

----------------Edit 1

```
cmTDsquery.bindStringProperty("batchname",CmTxnDetailStage.properties.batchName,batchNamePattern);
            cmTDsquery.bindStringProperty("batchname1",CmTxnDetailStage.properties.batchName,batchNamePattern1);
```

Sorry to mention this late , but above bindStringProperty methods works like a charm.
batchname and batchname1 contains "CR_STLM_UBROL%" and "%RMB_PINDBT%".

Comment: Where is this method "bindStringProperty"? There is no such method in Query. Show the code that where you declared "cmTDsquery " this variable?

Comment: @Naman ,Here is the declaration - Query<CmTxnDetailStage_Id> cmTDsquery = null;

Comment: This syntax doesn't seems that you are using hibernate for querying db.

Answer (score 2):

Do like this while setting parameter

"%"+search+"%"

Comment: cmTDsquery.bindStringProperty("search1",    CmTxnDetailStage.properties.prodTypeBlfd, search+"%");  does not resolves the issue. I even used cmTDsquery.bindStringProperty("search1",    CmTxnDetailStage.properties.prodTypeBlfd, "MON%"); but still no success.

Comment: seems true. I have not seen bindStringProperty any where. What are you trying to do with bindStringProperty?

Comment: You can write cmTDsquery.setParameter("search1",search+"%");

Comment: Hi Naman,I am working ORMB product(Oracle Revenue Management and Billing)2.0.2.It uses Hibernate feature for querying the DB.The setParameter is absent in our library ,instead we use bindStringProperty.Is there any difference?

Comment: If you are using hibernate for querying db then it is not possible that setParameter method is not available. You have taken query object of some different class. Take Query object of javax.Persistense

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand exactly the line

```
cmTDsquery.bindStringProperty("search1",    CmTxnDetailStage.properties.prodTypeBlfd, search);
```

Do you set the correct value - "MON%" and not for example "MON"?
I have used HQL like query.setParameter("search1","MON%") and it worked fine with like operators.

Answer (score 0):

My code is almost the same :

```
whereClause = whereClause + (whereClause.length() > 0 ? "AND " : "") + "ac.name LIKE :name ";
```

And further in my code :

```
if (searchCriteria.getNameSearchOperator() == SQL_STRING_SEARCH_OPERATORS.CONTAINS) {
    value = "%" + value + "%";
}
if (searchCriteria.getNameSearchOperator() == SQL_STRING_SEARCH_OPERATORS.START_WITH) {
    value = value + "%";
}
query.setParameter("name", value);
```

Try using `setParameter` instead of `bindStringProperty`.

Comment: Hi Wis , Whats the class of query. Can you explain with an example. Thanks

Comment: Here query is object of javax.persistence.Query class

Comment: Naman is right, I'm using the `javax.persistence.Query` object, which is what is proposed by JPA (independently of the underlying implementation, Hibernate or any other ORM, event if Hibernate is largely used).